# Is there any difference in order when using pipe and Write-Output

Tags: powershell

I'm not an expert on powershell but today I came across this line of code (note that `Write-Output` is only used as an example):

```
"Foo" | Write-Output
```

I wonder if it is any different from what I would expect:

```
Write-Output "Foo"
```

Comment: Or `'foo' | write-output -InputObject { $_ } `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In *effect* the two statements **should be equivalent**:

- In `Write-Output "Foo"`, `"Foo"` is implicitly bound to positional parameter `-InputObject`, which accepts type `PSObject[]`, i.e., an array of objects of any type.
- In `"Foo" | Write-Output`, by virtue of parameter `-InputObject` being defined as optionally accepting pipeline input (by value, i.e. whole objects), `"Foo"` is also bound to `-InputObject`.

I assume you chose `Write-Output` as an example, but it's worth nothing that there's rarely a good reason to use that cmdlet explicitly - simply omitting it in your examples would yield the same results.

Furthermore, **there *are* several cmdlets where the two forms are *not* equivalent**, namely those where `-InputObject` is defined as a *scalar* (with exceptions); consider the following:

```
 1, 2 | Get-Member              # reports [System.Int32]
 Get-Member -InputObject 1, 2   # reports [System.Object[]]
```

- `1, 2 | Get-Member` reports the type members for *each* element in the input array.
- `Get-Member -InputObject 1, 2`, by contrast, reports the members of the *array* type itself.

This difference in behavior is intentional and documented: using the *parameter* (`-InputObject`) allows inspecting *collection* types *as a whole*, whereas using the *pipeline* allows inspecting a collection's individual *elements'* types.

Note that there are cmdlets that exhibit the same difference in behavior, even though passing collections as a whole to them doesn't make much sense, such as `Export-Csv`; in such cases, always use the *pipeline* - see [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/4242) for background information.

---

To **determine what parameters of a cmdlet accept pipeline input** and thus understand what parameter pipeline input will be bound to:

- **To see the parameters in the context of the full help topic**:

  - Run `Get-Help -Full <cmdlet>`; using `-Full` is crucial.
  - Search for occurrences of `true (`, which will match parameters that accept:

    - pipeline input by value (whole object) only: `true (ByValue)`
    - pipeline input by property name only: `true (ByPropertyName)`
    - either: `true (ByValue, ByPropertyName)`
    - More generally, each parameter description has an `Accept pipeline input?` line item followed by a Boolean.
- To extract **just the names and their aliases, data types, and binding characteristics** (using `Rename-Item` as an example):

  ```
  Get-Help Rename-Item -Parameter * | Where-Object pipelineInput -like 'true*' |
    Select-Object Name, Aliases, Type, pipelineInput
  ```