# How to remotely rename a list of computers via PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, csv, batch-processing

I have a largish set of Windows 10 workstations that need to be renamed. I've tried running the script below, but get errors that are beyond my current PS level.

```
$computers = Import-Csv "c:\rename-computers\computers.csv" 
foreach ($oldname in $computers){
    #Write-Host "EmpID=" + $computers.NewName
    Rename-Computer -ComputerName $computers.OldName -NewName $computers.NewName -DomainCredential hole\inwall -Force -Restart
}
```

Produces:

> Rename-Computer : Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type
>   'System.String' required by parameter 'ComputerName'.  Specified
>   method is not supported. At
>   \siat-ds0\appdeploy\LabPacks\rename-computers\rename-siat.ps1:4
>   char:35
>   +     Rename-Computer -ComputerName $computers.OldName -NewName $computers.NewName ...
>   +                                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Rename-Computer], ParameterBindingException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgument,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RenameComputerCommand

I've seen similar closed threads on this topic elsewhere without mention of the error I'm receiving.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**You mistakenly used the *collection* variable `$computers` instead of the *loop-iteration* variable `$oldname` inside your loop**, and since `$computers.NewName` expanded to an *array* of names rather than a single one, you got the error you saw.

That said, **you don't need a loop at all** - a single pipeline will do:

```
Import-Csv "c:\rename-computers\computers.csv" |
 Rename-Computer -ComputerName { $_.OldName } -DomainCredential hole\inwall -Force -Restart
```

`Rename-Computer` will implicitly bind the `NewName` property of each input object to the `-NewName` parameter.

The `-ComputerName` parameter, by contrast, must be told what property on the input objects to access, given that the input objects have no `ComputerName` property.
This is what script block `{ $_.OldName }` does, inside which automatic variable `$_` represents the input object at hand.

To see which parameters accept pipeline input, examine the output from
`Get-Help -full Rename-Computer`; for details and a programmatic alternative, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35473988/45375) of mine.

Answer (score 1):

You are iterating but not using the singular:

Instead of this:

```
foreach ($oldname in $computers){
    #Write-Host "EmpID=" + $computers.NewName
    Rename-Computer -ComputerName $computers.OldName -NewName $computers.NewName -DomainCredential hole\inwall -Force -Restart
}
```

Try this:

```
foreach ($oldname in $computers){
    Rename-Computer -ComputerName $oldname.OldName -NewName $oldname.NewName -DomainCredential hole\inwall -Force -Restart
}
```

**Note:** `$oldname` is holding one value at a point. So the number of computers present in `$computers` will come one by one to `$oldname` and will perform the activity inside the loop.

You should use the singular `$oldname` inside the loop to iterate one by one.

Answer (score 0):

[Bulk rename computers in AD](https://github.com/pedjaj/pedja_bulk_rename_ad_computers)
Powershell bulk rename computers in AD with test if pc is online and if new name is already taken and log "not-renamed" PC.

```
adc.csv 
oldname,newname 
WEDSKS0022,RKVKS0110 
WEDSKS0117,RKVKS1413
```

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Force;
$computers = import-csv -Path ".\adc.csv"
$Credential = Get-Credential
$nisuprosli=".\notrenamed $(get-date -f dd-MM-yyyy-HHMM).csv"
$makecsv="oldname,newname" | Out-File $nisuprosli -Encoding utf8 -Append

foreach ($pc in $computers){
   
 $IsOldPCalive=Test-Connection -ComputerName $pc.oldname -Quiet -Count 1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
 $IsNewPCalive=Test-Connection -ComputerName $pc.newname -Quiet -Count 1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

 if ($IsOldPCalive -eq $True -and $IsNewPCalive -eq $False) {
      write-host "Rename PC $($pc.oldname) u $($pc.newname)" -ForegroundColor Cyan
      Rename-computer -computername $pc.oldname -newname $pc.newname -domaincredential $Credential -PassThru -force -restart #-WhatIf   
         }
    else {
    write-host "PC $($pc.oldname) is not available or already exists $($pc.newname)" -ForegroundColor Yellow
    $makecsv="$($pc.oldname),$($pc.newname)" | Out-File $nisuprosli -Encoding utf8 -Append
    }

}
```

Comment: Yes,
I forgot to translate